# Custom information bubble on tap for overlay items using osmdroid

Tags: android, android-mapview, osmdroid

I'm using osmdroid on my new Android project (since I want to be able to use offline maps) but I encounter many difficulties to customize the look 'n feel of the information bubble assigned to an overlay item.

Right now, I'm using an `ItemizedOverlayWithFocus` overlay to display my items; looking at [its code](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/source/browse/trunk/osmdroid-android/src/org/osmdroid/views/overlay/ItemizedOverlayWithFocus.java?r=802), I noticed the whole thing was drawn in the `onDrawFinished` method so I tried to create my own custom overlay to override this method but this is pretty difficult to get a result. What I would love to get is something just like this :

[image: The result]

How did you guys managed to get a custom information bubble on your projects?

I found a few classes to implement such a thing for Google's MapView (like [Jeff Gilfelt's MapView Balloons](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons)) but nothing for osmdroid.

Comment: android-mapviewballoons should be using almost the same API. You didn't try porting it to osmdroid?

Comment: I'm trying right now but I'm debugging (I don't have any touch event triggered for example). But since i saw quite a few projects with nice looking information bubbles, I think I'm missing something easier than porting mapviewballoons.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**EDIT:**

- This answer was best for older google map apis. In google Map V2 this
  thing is already given.

You can get the code from <strike>https://github.com/galex/android-mapviewballoons</strike>

you can get selected balloon from the method of "BalloonItemizedOverlay.java" as follow

```
private void hideOtherBalloons(List<Overlay> overlays) {
        for(int i=0; i<overlays.size();i++ ){
            if (overlays.get(i) instanceof BalloonItemizedOverlay<?> && overlays.get(i) != this) {
                ((BalloonItemizedOverlay<?>) overlays.get(i)).hideBalloon();
            }else{
                BalloonOverlayView.SELECTED_BALLOON = i;
                Log.i(i+" : Baloon Open", BalloonOverlayView.SELECTED_BALLOON+"");
            }
        }
}
```

To set the data you can use setBalloonData method of BalloonOverlayView.java file as follow:

```
protected void setBalloonData(Item item, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (item.getTitle() != null) {
            title.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            title.setText(item.getTitle());
        } else {
            title.setText("");
            title.setVisibility(GONE);
        }
        if (item.getSnippet() != null) {
            snippet.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            snippet.setText(item.getSnippet());
        } else {
            snippet.setText("");
            snippet.setVisibility(GONE);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You should check out this new library, OSM bonus pack. Should do exactly what you want.

http://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/