# How to set multiple GeoPoint with a related activity for eachone on a map

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, android-mapview, android-maps

I have a list of Home, each Home is an object with latitude, longitude, name and description.
Now I want to view all homes as geopoint in the android MapView.

I have searched in the site for something about, and I have seen that need a map overlay.

So I have done this in the SearchHome Activity (that is the activity with the map and the search box)

```
MapLocationOverlay mapLocationOverlay = new MapLocationOverlay(SearchHome.this, elementi, SearchHome.this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.home_icon));
            overlays = mapView.getOverlays();
            overlays.add(mapLocationOverlay);
```

My MapOverlay class is:

```
public class MapLocationOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {

   private List<Home> homeList;
   private Context context;

   public MapLocationOverlay(Context context, List<Home> homeList, Drawable marker) {
      super(boundCenterBottom(marker));
      this.context = context;
      this.homeList = homeList;
      if (homeList == null) {
          homeList = new ArrayList<Home>();
      }
      populate();
   }

   @Override
   protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
       Home c=homeList.get(i);
       GeoPoint point =
               new GeoPoint((int) ((Double.valueOf(c.getLatitude()) * 1e6)), (int) ((Double.valueOf(c.getLongitude()) * 1e6)));
      return new OverlayItem(point, c.getNameHouse(), null);
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onTap(final int index) {
      Home h = homelist.get(index);
      AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
      builder.setTitle("HomeLocation")
               .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                     Intent i = new Intent(context, HouseDetails.class);
                     i.putExtra(HomeMapApp.index, index);
                     context.startActivity(i);
                  }
               }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                     dialog.cancel();
                  }
               });
      AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
      alert.show();

      return true; // we'll handle the event here (true) not pass to another overlay (false)
   }

   @Override
   public int size() {
      return homeList.size();
   }
}
```

**But I don't know how to configure the listener onTap to handle properly the related House item in the map with the GeoPoint.**

For example If I click on the geopoint *MyHouse in New York* I should get all the data of the respective House java object and send it to HouseDetail class tho show the info.

Comment: "But doesn't work" -- what happens? What have you tried since?

Comment: Ok was unclear. Now I have edited my question for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have answered the same type question take a look at my answer most probably it will answer your question

[Custom information bubble on tap for overlay items using osmdroid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9362137/custom-information-bubble-on-tap-for-overlay-items-using-osmdroid/9461841#9461841)

Comment: Thanks, now I have edited my question, 

could you give me more details?