# How to adding balloons title in open street map?

Tags: android

i am using this open streetmap from this [Implementing Open Street Map](http://android-coding.blogspot.com/2012/06/example-of-implementing-openstreetmap.html), the code is working fine but problem is i want to add a balloon like google map  which  show in this image   [Android Mapview Balloons](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons).

Please tell me how can i do that?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: it is possible to add balloon in Open Street Map?????

Answer (score 0):

Create multi-marker OpenStreetMap for Android

http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/05/create-multi-marker-openstreetmap-for.html

Answer (score 0):

If u are using eclipse import [mapviewbaloons](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons) library into your project and than extend MyItemizedOverlay

```
public class MyItemizedOverlay extends BalloonItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem>
```

Your onTap will have to become onBaloonTap

```
@Override
protected boolean onBalloonTap(int index, OverlayItem item) {
    String url = "someurl.com";
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    c.startActivity(i);
    return true;

}
```

Make sure that you add Context when you start activity in onBaloonTap() in this example c is Context

```
c.startActivity(i);
```

Comment: u mean i add googlemapview baloonitemized clas in this application?

Comment: When you add it as a library to your project you will be able to use it. Right click project->properties->android and at the bottom add library.

Comment: what libraries i add?   osm library or mapviebaloons class??

Comment: u mean add this 2 classes  https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons/tree/master/android-mapviewballoons/src/com/readystatesoftware/mapviewballoons   in my application??

Comment: You should already imported OSM as external jar in your libs folder and mapviewbaloons is library so you add it as a library as I explained

Comment: import OSM like it is explained  here http://android-coding.blogspot.hk/2012/06/osmdroid-interact-with-openstreetmap-to.html

Comment: is not help me so confusing

Comment: i imprt osm but when i change this line ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> to  BalloonItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem  so many error s come

Comment: The constructor BalloonItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem>(Drawable, ResourceProxy) is undefined

Comment: The method add(Overlay) in the type List<Overlay> is not applicable for the arguments (MyItemizedOverlay)

Comment: OK check out these two links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9362137/custom-information-bubble-on-tap-for-overlay-items-using-osmdroid  http://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/