# how to add balloon overlay in osm map application

Tags: android

How do I add balloon overlay in this my osm code? I'm using osm map and I want to show balloon overlay like google maps  I want to implement [this](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons) in my code which is below:

```
import org.osmdroid.DefaultResourceProxyImpl;
import org.osmdroid.ResourceProxy;
import org.osmdroid.util.GeoPoint;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapView;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapController;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 MyItemizedOverlay myItemizedOverlay = null;
 private MapController myMapController;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    myMapController = mapView.getController();
    myMapController.setZoom(16);


    Drawable marker=getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.star_big_on);
    int markerWidth = marker.getIntrinsicWidth();
    int markerHeight = marker.getIntrinsicHeight();
    marker.setBounds(0, markerHeight, markerWidth, 0);

    ResourceProxy resourceProxy = new    
 DefaultResourceProxyImpl(getApplicationContext());

    myItemizedOverlay = new MyItemizedOverlay(marker, resourceProxy);
    mapView.getOverlays().add(myItemizedOverlay);

    GeoPoint myPoint1 = new GeoPoint(24.893379000000000000, 67.028060900000010000);
    myItemizedOverlay.addItem(myPoint1, "myPoint1", "myPoint1");
    GeoPoint myPoint2 = new GeoPoint(24.824796300000000000, 67.031565699999990000);
    myItemizedOverlay.addItem(myPoint2, "myPoint2", "myPoint2");


 } 

 }

import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.osmdroid.ResourceProxy;
import org.osmdroid.api.IMapView;
import org.osmdroid.util.GeoPoint;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.ItemizedOverlay;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.OverlayItem;

   import android.graphics.Point;
  import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

 public class MyItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {

 private ArrayList<OverlayItem> overlayItemList = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();

 public MyItemizedOverlay(Drawable pDefaultMarker,
  ResourceProxy pResourceProxy) {
 super(pDefaultMarker, pResourceProxy);
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
  }

  public void addItem(GeoPoint p, String title, String snippet){
   OverlayItem newItem = new OverlayItem(title, snippet, p);
   overlayItemList.add(newItem);
   populate(); 
 }

 @Override
public boolean onSnapToItem(int arg0, int arg1, Point arg2, IMapView arg3) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 return false;
}

 @Override
 protected OverlayItem createItem(int arg0) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 return overlayItemList.get(arg0);
}

 @Override
 public int size() {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 return overlayItemList.size();
}

}
```

Comment: Look at this:  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9362137/custom-information-bubble-on-tap-for-overlay-items-using-osmdroid