# Sample code for osmBonusPack

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I'm writing an android app which uses offline maps.For this I'm using osmdroid, I've come across this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9362137/custom-information-bubble-on-tap-for-overlay-items-using-osmdroid) which refers to an update of osmdroid the osmbonuspack. Can you point me at some tutorials and sample codes besides those provided by the openstreetsmap so that I can get started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is working link https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack.

Please let me know if links are dead.

Comment: Above OSM link is dead

Comment: Dead links, nowadays.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I updated the link.

Answer (score 0):

This implementation (app:Gradle) worked for me in Android Studio using SDK 29:

```
implementation 'com.github.MKergall.osmbonuspack:OSMBonusPack:v5.7'
```

You can find this [MKergall's Maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.MKergall.osmbonuspack/OSMBonusPack/v5.7)

NOTE: you will have to comment out your previous osmdroid (mine was 4.3) jar implementation, because methods are duplicated.